# Can an Android phone control Ubuntu like a remote?

Tags: android, remote-desktop, media

I am looking at making a budget media centre. I am new to Linux and have not yet installed it but think I can manage. I want to use Ubuntu and would like to use my Android phones to control or work as a remote for media playing to a TV.

My setup will be the media box to TV via [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) (no keyboard or mouse connected) then to my Wi-Fi router via Ethernet.

So I want to be able to turn this PC on and after it's booted directly from my phone control the PC remotely to open the media application and run videos and open photos directly to the TV.

I am using a [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II) and soon a new Sony for the wife.

Comment: Not an answer at all, but some geeks may smile at the fact that I love using PuTTy on my mobile to connect via SSH to my laptop instead of standing up from a comfy chair, and walking few meters to turn the volume down ;)

Answer (score 25):

If you install the [xbmc](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ppa) packages (and use that environment), you can control your machine from android, because there is an app called [xbmc remote](http://xbmc.org/freezy3k/2010/07/13/official-xbmc-remote-for-android/) in google play.
It works flawlessly for me.

Comment: Xbmc now included in 12.04 repository

Comment: Its name is now `kodi`.

Comment: Kore is the official Android app for kodi: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore and for iOS this client works https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/official-kodi-remote/id520480364 (not sure if it's really official or not)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [anyRemote](http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/dload.html)
too

Comment: Works very well... as a remote. You can control Video players and stuff very easily, but it does not rally work as a mouse or keyboard...

Answer (score 8):

There's actually an Android app written specifically for this use case. It's called [Couch Potato](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codes.soloware.couchpotato.free). In addition to providing a virtual mouse and keyboard, it allows you to register your machine, and subsequently boot it by sending a Wake-on-LAN packet.

Full disclosure: I'm the developer.

Comment: Wake on LAN is a nice feature :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks! Glad you like it! :-)

Comment: I just tried it... Ubuntu package depends on Java7 which is no more available. Even though I downloaded java binary ant tested with Java 8 and 9. In both I could use mouse which I must say it works perfectly. But, sadly, in tha android app I wasn't able to open the keyboard. Am I missing something?. Thanks.

Comment: @bitifet Sorry for the trouble! I've filed two issues based on your comment, which can be found [here](https://github.com/rarcher/couch-potato-server/issues/22) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/ryanarcher/couch-potato-client/issues/39/cannot-access-keyboard). Firstly, the Java 7 dependency should only kick in if your default Java package is older than that. I'm honestly surprised you even got a notification about it, but in any case, it isn't necessary anymore, and will be removed. As for the keyboard issue, that sounds like something device-specific. What model of phone are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My device is an BQ Aquaris M5 running Android 6.0.1. My Keyboard is MessagEase (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb&hl=ca ) even I'm pretty sure I tried temporary switching back to device's default with no look (not at 100% because I was testing other alternatives too but I'm almost sure I did).

Comment: @bitifet I have not been able to duplicate this issue in the app's current test suite, so I'm going to order a BQ Aquaris M5 off the 'Net.  Hopefully we'll be able to get to the bottom of this once it arrives.

Comment: I'm sorry you tabe that trouble. And I really appreciate your dedication. I could try again more deeply if you want: I was testing various options but maybe not so deeply (I'm thinking that I did'nt even rebooted my device to discard any unusual situation).

I will be glad to test again even I'm sorry that now I can't say when I could do that because of personal circumstances.

In any case, thanks again for your dedication. I will for sure give it another try and of course report the results,

Comment: @bitifet It's no problem really. Just to make sure we're on the same page, are you able to get into the touch pad screen's menu at all? Or is the keyboard just not launching when you click the option for it?

Comment: Tried again. I downloaded the server Debian Package linked from Google Play Store and installed it though `dpkg -i`. It complained again because the lack of Java 7 or Java Default, but after installing Java Default it ran Ok (Just I achieved last time by downloading .jar file I think).

After that, server started and I could connect from my smartphone. But, unfortunately, things went the same way again: Mouse functions worked well, but I'm not able to open the keyboard.

Next I switched to my Android's default keyboard (gboard) also with no luck (even dischargin and reopening the app) :-(

Comment: @bitifet The complaints about Java are just because the new build hasn't been released yet. But regarding the keyboard issue, are you able to use other options menu functions? Like, can you successfully register the server with your phone?

Comment: I don't see any menú: just a black screen that acts as touchpad and three buttons at the bottom the whole thing acting as (perfectly working) remote mouse control.

Comment: About the Java complain I mentioned it just for the sake of completeness. But if new version hasn't been released yet, then I should have been wrong in some way first time tested because I thought I could'nt install it even being installed Java 8 and/or 9 (I remember I tried both). I figure out I could see that complain and missunderstood it thinking package had not been installed. I apologize for not so thorough testing. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @bitifet The menu is actually at the bottom of the screen, and is triggered by the arrow button. It's set up that way so that people don't accidentally click on ads while trying to access it. I apologize if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Which arrow button? The "back" hardware button you mean? This returns me to the server selection screen. The only buttons I see in the app are the three mouse buttons.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I see (private server with invalid certificate: you will need to accept it, sorry): https://nigul.bitifet.net:2000/nextcloud/index.php/s/EO2AmExzPlUFQZ0

Comment: @bitifet There's supposed to be an arrow button under the mouse buttons, which is apparently not rendering on your phone for some reason. I've not been able to duplicate this issue, even on an identical device...could I get you to post an [Android bug report](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html) off your phone? And in the meantime, I'd also like to give you a free copy of the paid version, for all the trouble; it shouldn't have the bug, as it uses a different menu creation method. I've e-mailed a promo code for it to the address posted on your profile.

Comment: Done. I just send it to you, @Blank .
Thanks again for all your good work!!
You're right in that in paid version menu works perfectly and I could open the keyboard.
I also would say that it works perfectly and much more fluid than any other option I tried before (all of those unusable for me) so, if anyone have the same issue with the free version (or even if not: it is too cheap!) I recommend to purchase the paid one :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) (a popular video/music player) in Ubuntu you could use one of the apps from [the Google play store.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=adarshurs.android.vlcmobileremote&hl=csfeature=search_result)

Comment: ... and VLC has a web interface too

Answer (score 4):

I found only one app that is free, generic (not written specifically to work with a certain program), doesn't require installing special custom server software for that app, and is able to connect to my computer (well… after working with the author to find and fix an unreasonable restriction).

It is [XMouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stripe1.xmouse&hl=en) and it is [open-source](https://github.com/bradand/XMouse). No ads and no nags. You can use it as a mouse, keyboard, or remote control with programmable buttons (execute any command you want). Maybe not the greatest user interface (takes some time to understand and get used to it), but it works well.

The only requirements are ssh and xdotool (well, xdotool is not 100% required, but I think it's at least needed for the mouse and keyboard functionality).

Comment: exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

I used the standart VNC server (`Desktop Sharing` app in Ubuntu) and [PocketCloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wyse.pocketcloudfree&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53eXNlLnBvY2tldGNsb3VkZnJlZSJd).

It's easy to setup and works well.

You can find instruction here: [click](http://maketecheasier.com/remote-control-ubuntu-from-android-tablet/2011/12/20).

Answer (score 3):

### VNC

There is a way to do it and its free plus also no need to use the Internet.

1. Install any VNC server from the list like TightVNC, UltraVNC, TigerVNC, or RealVNC, although encryption is not supported with the latter.
2. Create a hotspot without internet if you want and connect your laptop and your Android phone in the same network.
3. Install [bVNC Secure VNC Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freebVNC) on your Android phone.

The bVNC app is a VNC viewer.It can also emulate a touchpad or let you use Android as a mouse with support for touchscreen gestures. You can save sessions, zoom and scale the Linux desktop on the Android screen, and share the text in the clipboard between Android and PC.

Answer (score 3):

### GSConnect/KDE Connect

GNOME Shell Connect (GSConnect) lets you use the KDE Connect mobile application to control (recent) versions of Ubuntu running GNOME Shell.

In my experience it works very well OOTB and is quite configurable, with support for custom launchers, two-way push notifications, message replies, file sharing, media control, etc. in addition to keyboard and mouse support.

- [GSConnect GNOME Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/)
- [GSConnect Homepage](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki)
- [KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect)

Answer (score 2):

An application that comes close to doing this is [RemoteDroid](http://www.remotedroid.net/). It makes your touchscreen phone work like a wireless touchpad + keyboard combination.

There are two separate applications you need to download for this - one for your linux machine (server) and another for your Android Phone.

Answer (score 2):

I have good experience with [Home Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inspiredandroid.linuxcontrolcenter). Works good with linux.

You can control:

- media (play, stop, volume, ...)
- mouse, keyboard,
- browse folders, upload / download files to smartphone
- run a command

All those are "shortcuts" organized to "shotcut groups" and are implemented / can be configured with custom commands.

There is no need to install anything on Ubuntu (just xdotools for media control by commands). The connection is by username/password or by ssh-key/passphrase

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend

http://openelec.tv/

Which uses XBMC and has configured shares for easily coping media to the media center. It is a very simple install and requires minimal hardware.

Answer (score 1):

### [Kore](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.xbmc.kore/) to control [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/)/[Kodi](https://kodi.tv/)

Kore and Yatse are what I use for my OSMC setup on Pi.

1. Install kodi on Ubuntu.

   ```
    sudo apt install kodi
   ```
2. Launch kodi and navigate to
3. Services option under it and set the Settings level to Advanced / Expert.
4. Navigate to the Control option then Allow remote control via HTTP and also Allow remote control from applications on another system.
5. Go back to Settings Menu on Kodi as shown in Step 1 and navigate to System info
6. Navigate to System info and under Network note the IP Address and MAC Address. You will need them to set up on Application on the iPhone / iPad/Android.
7. and then install the app on your android phone.

   - [Kore on Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore&hl=en_EN)
   - [Kore on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.xbmc.kore/)
   - [Yatse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree&hl=en_EN) (paid alternative, free to download)

After Kore/Yatse 's installation, all you need to do is enter the ip into the app and you will be good to go.

[Reference](https://kodi.wiki/view/Remote_controls)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Remote Computer Over Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.polytech.remotecomputer
free and without ads

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Chrome Remote Desktop extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp) then the Debian binaries. Connect and you are good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [AndroMouse](http://andromouse.com/) offers a *dead-easy setup* and is full of features. You just have to run a java app in your server (your Ubuntu desktop) and the Android app on the client (your phone). Then, you have two options to connect the client to the server: Wi-fi or Bluetooth. Then the app auto-searches for the server; if it's not found, you can insert the easily-visible server IP on the client to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed the [Linux Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.linuxremote.app) Android app exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **TeamViewer**. This simple and easy tool to control your pc using your android device. You need to install teamviwer in ubuntu and android mobile.