# How do I install LibreOffice 4?

Tags: libreoffice, software-installation

I want to download and install [LibreOffice 4](http://www.libreoffice.org/#0).  How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to try a new LO version out before installing it, [here's a nice tutorial](http://simos.info/blog/archives/1196). You might want to make a backup of your LO configuration files first, though (`~/.config/libreoffice`).

Comment: From the answers below, it seems there are 4 options: 1) uninstall your existing LO and then download and **manually** install the latest LO; 2) use the "rather unstable" **pre-releases ppa**; 3) use the new "not-so-stable" **libreoffice-4-0 ppa**; and 4) wait for a more stable ubuntu package to be ready in the **main libreoffice ppa**. Therefore, **it might be useful to hear from the experiences in categories 1, 2 and 3**.

Comment: @Sadi I used my method to install it and it worked just fine.  I've had no issues what so ever, though I must admit I don't tinker with it, just use the default setup for the most part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running a newer version of Ubuntu you can get various versions of LibreOffice 4 right from the repos:

- 14.10 has LibreOffice 4.3.3
- 14.04 has LibreOffice 4.2
- 13.10 has LibreOffice 4.1
- 13.04 has LibreOffice 4.0.2

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Or use the software center.

If you want the absolute latest version of LibreOffice follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/264047/44179).

Answer (score 84):

You can use the [Libreoffice 4.4 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-4) from the libreoffice packaging team, which offers stable backports for Precise (12.04), Trusty (14.04), Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04).

**Note:** if you rely on `libreoffice` for work or school you may not want to risk updating, even though the backports provided are largely stable.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Obviously, if you don't already have libreoffice installed, you will also need to run

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

It should be noted that this ppa will only produce updates for the 4.4 series, while the [main libreoffice ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) will provide updates beyond the 4.4 series, although that ppa is largely for testing and development builds.

(The original 4.0 series ppa [is here at launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0), if anyone has any special reason to use that series.)

For more information, see [this very recent useful article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-libreoffice-40-in-ubuntu-1204.html) on `libreoffice` 4, and the [getting started guide](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/1/13/GS40-GettingStartedLO.pdf) at the official documentation site.

Comment: Using this new PPA, upgrade from 3.6 to 4.0 went very well (Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit) and the applications seems very stable with noticeable performance improvements. I only had to re-install several extensions, rename several macros added to the Format menu and rename a custom menu back to Macros. Upvoted!

Comment: @Sadi Yes, the upgrade went smoothly for me as well; this ppa from the libreoffice team does provide stable backports with  several Ubuntu tweaks included.

Comment: Adding `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0/ubuntu precise main` and `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0/ubuntu precise main` to my software sources brought up the ["Not all updates can be installed" message](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58928/update-manager-says-not-all-updates-can-be-installed). Just in case that's of interest to anyone...

Comment: @Mik Sorry, I submitted the comment with only the link accidentally first; hope it makes more sense now; that's just the usual way I add ppa's, rather than by the command-line; was wondering, if the command-line way you described would also throw that message, or if I should go by [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/58934/16023) method, instead...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I see now. I usually do it all using the command-line, but you can sometimes get errors. Usually `ppa-purge` is a good way to correct them. I answered a question the other day relating to Libreoffice 4 [installation issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269976/after-libreoffice-updated-it-wont-start/270008#270008).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you don't have the previous version of LibreOffice installed on your system, additionally to the commands mentioned by Mik, you also need to run the following one: `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

Comment: @Krige Yes, that's true, but I thought it was obvious; however, I will add the point to the answer.

Comment: Would this upgrade my distro version? For example, I'm running 12.04.2 right now, will following these instructions attempt upgrade from this version? I'm only concerned about the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` line.

Comment: @oaskamay No, you won't be upgraded to any later Ubuntu versions; you have to use `dist-upgrade` when updating the kernel using the command-line as well. You can always use the `-s` switch with apt-get if you wish, so you can see what the command would do: ie. use `apt-get -s dist-upgrade` after adding the ppa and running `sudo apt-get update`. Then you can see there will be no problems.

Comment: Is this PPA updated for LibreOffice 4.1?

Comment: @Seth I have updated the answer, and will keep it updated when 4.2, etc, comes out. I meant to update it a while ago.

Comment: The libreoffice 4.4 PPA appears to no longer support precise (12.04).  After I did the "apt-get update" I got some "Failed to fetch..." errors.  So instead I used the 4.3 PPA with the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-3`

Answer (score 65):

## This method is not recommended!

While using this method will still work fine, and you will end up with the latest version of LibreOffice, LibreOffice 4.2 is now available in the Trusty repositories and the recommended method of installation is [using the software center or apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/388367/44179).

If you want to live on the wild side, or you want the absolute latest and greatest version of LibreOffice use this answer.

If you find something out of date, please leave a comment below or go ahead and fix it yourself :)

---

Start by downloading it:

- Direct torrent link:  [LibreOffice 4.3.4 torrent 64 bit](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.3.4/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz.torrent) or [LibreOffice 4.3.4 torrent 32 bit](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/4.3.4/deb/x86/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz.torrent)
- Normal installer direct link: [LibreOffice 4.3.4 normal installer 64 bit](http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/deb-x86_64/4.3.4/en-US/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz)  or [LibreOffice 4.3.0 normal installer 32 bit](http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/deb-x86/4.3.4/en-US/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz)

I recommend the torrent for faster download speed and for slow connections.

---

To install LibreOffice 4 you will need to remove all previous versions. Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

*Note:*  I'm not 100% sure this will remove *all* of LibreOffice.  If you experience any errors later, please let me know.

---

## Extract the files:

1. `cd` to the Downloads directory:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   ```
2. Extract the `tar.gz`:

   For 64 bit:

   ```
   tar -xvzf LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
   ```

   For 32 bit:

   ```
   tar -xvzf LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz
   ```

## Install the program:

1. `cd` to the programs folder:

   For 64 bit:

   ```
   cd LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS
   ```

   For 32 bit:

   ```
   cd LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86_deb/DEBS
   ```
2. Install part one (for both 32 and 64 bit):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

You're done!  You can now remove both the directory and the tarball:

```
rm -r ~/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb 
rm ~/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.3.4_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
```

Go add the [re-add the applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/37434/44179) to your launcher!

Some Kubuntu users will need to run this command to fix how LibreOffice 4 looks in KDE:

```
sudo mv /opt/libreoffice/ure/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/libreoffice/ure/lib/libstdc++.so.6.old
```

Comment: How can I **migrate** my **settings**, in particular my **custom templates**, from `libreoffice 3` to `libreoffice 4`? Spontaneously, I can think of some "manual" ways of doing it; what are the options, what's the best/safest/most convenient way to do so?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty That should be a new question ;)

Comment: How about just rewriting the whole answer instead?

Comment: @Braiam I guess I could add the other answer onto this one, but this one is still as valid as any of the others.

Comment: A very good answer but makes no mention of installing the language and help packs for the users locality.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the beta packaged for Ubuntu from the LibreOffice pre-releases ppa:

https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-prereleases

Comment: I recommend expanding this to explain *how* to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Via terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice -y
```

By using the official ppa you'll always have the latest LibreOffice stable release, regardless your Ubuntu version (at least until it become obsolete, so 14.04, 12.04 and the upcoming 15.04 are fully supported).

Answer (score 1):

Instructions are on this Web Upd8 article:  [LibreOffice 4.0 Available For Download](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/libreoffice-40-available-for-download.html).

Differs from [Seth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/252613/22949) only in copying the desktop integration `.deb` from one location to another before the `dpkg` command.

Comment: this installs Libreoffice 5, how doI get 4?