# Can't upgrade to LibreOffice 4

Tags: libreoffice

I tried to upgrade my LibreOffice to 4.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04, but now it doesn't work anymore.
If I try to install LibreOffice again, I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.0~rc4-0ubuntu3~ppa1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.6.0~rc4-0ubuntu3~ppa1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libreoffice-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Would be so great, if anybody could help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you tried to install LO4?  We need to know the commands you used and what guide you followed.  Thanks!

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install libreoffice' is what I tried, then I got the code I postet! I don't need libreOffice 4.0, I just want any LibreOffice back on my PC.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it [this way](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/libreoffice-40-available-for-download.html)?

I did it like that yesterday and it works perfectly!

Comment: This is what happens `dpkg: error processing /path/to/libreoffice/DEBS/*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /path/to/libreoffice/DEBS/*.deb`

Comment: Please read the command in the tutorial carefully! `/path/to/libreoffice/DEBS/*.deb` has to be repleased by YOUR path where you downloaded libreoffice.

Comment: oh, stupid, my fault.. ;) It works, thousand thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, we all made those mistakes at the beginning ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to force Ubuntu to upgrade to version 4.0 by typing the following in a terminal (press enter after each line).

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If you don't have LibreOffice installed for whatever reason, then instead of the last line, type this.

`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4) question to upgrade to **LibreOffice4.0**.