# Can't un-tar LibreOffice 4 download

Tags: libreoffice, tar

I've tried this guide 
[How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4)

But I get this message

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is happening? And can someone tell me how to download it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install LibreOffice 4?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4)

Comment: @EricCarvalho No, this isn't a duplicate.  I have edited the title to clarify that.

Comment: I hear using the .deb file does not work too well; it leaves out some Ubuntu-centric features. I found it best to force Ubuntu to upgrade to version 4.0 by typing the following in a terminal (press enter after each line). <code>
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa<br>
sudo apt-get update<br>
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
</code> If you don't have LibreOffice installed for whatever reason, then instead of the last line, type this. <code>
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
</code>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You downloaded the `.rpm` file. `.rpm` is used by Fedora and Red Hat, but Ubuntu and Debian use `.deb`.

The correct command to un-tar this file would be:

```
tar -xvzf LibreOffice_4.0.0_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
```

Did you download using the links from my post?  They link to the proper `.deb` files.

Comment: Hmm, no i didn't. I went to the official site and just downloaded it lol

Comment: @Kamerom Okay, then you must have downloaded the Fedora installer ;)

Comment: @Kamerom Yes, you can delete the `rpm` now.