# LibreOffice 4.0's menu bar is not integrated with Unity

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice, panel, hud, menu-bar

One of the most interesting features of the new LibreOffice 4 is the direct compatibility with Unity's Panel and HUD.

[image]

So I've just installed this wonderful new release. Everything works fine... except for *that*, so as an active user of every existing HUD at Ubuntu, I would like to know how to enable it, as I haven't found any info in LibreOffice's Wiki, in Ask Ubuntu or in the web in general.

Please do NOT post `lo-menubar` because it just won't work.

Comment: Now you can [install from the Libreoffice 4.0 PPA](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4/264047#264047) and avoid cannibalizing `lo-menubar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Menubar extension is working for me, but not the lo-menubar*.deb - the guts of this package. I don't know how long it would be working. This is very ugly hack and use it at your own risk. Just check it out: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12515508#post12515508

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, libreoffice 4.0.0 and menubar 0.1.1. I don't know if this is working in 12.10, but really want to know.

Comment: It does work in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: The folder /usr/lib/libreoffice doesn't exists in my Ubuntu :(

Comment: That's because LO 4.0 is in /opt/libreoffice4.0 :) In  /usr/lib/libreoffice was ubuntu's libreoffice.

Comment: So I have to reinstall LibreOffice 3 just to copy the toolbar? Whoa, I'd love to download thousands of MB to get just a few ones! ^^

Comment: Just download [lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lo-menubar/lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) for amd64 or [lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lo-menubar/lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb) for i386. Unpack it using `mc` or file roller. Find `menubar` folder in `extensions` folder and copy to `/opt/libreoffice4.0/share/extensions/`.

Comment: More like a prosthesis! ;)

Comment: Yes, wrzomar's method works well!

Answer (score 1):

How did you install LibreOffice 4.0?  Did you use the .deb file?  I have heard this does not provide the Ubuntu-centric features, like the menu bar integration.  I installed by adding the official LibreOffice ppa and running a dist-upgrade; this seemed to work great!  Menu bar is integrated and it replaced the old LibreOffice; even my custom shortcuts on the launcher launched the new vesion.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you don't have LibreOffice installed for whatever reason, then instead of the last line, type this.

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, even the workaround with lo-menubar did not work. I was stuck in a situation where I couldnt install an older version of libre office with lo-menubar - because i couldn't install lo-menubar as long as there is a mismatch in some dependencies.

Here is my solution to get at least the old LO Version working with HUD again:

- completely deinstall LO 4
- install the recent LO 3.6
- follow the instructions of wrzomar: download lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb for amd64 or lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb for i386 (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12515508#post12515508). Unpack it.  Find menubar folder in extensions folder and copy to /opt/libreoffice3.6/share/extensions/.

==> now I have libre office 3.6 and HUD working again