# Warning while running LibreOffice4.0

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I installed **LibreOffice4.0** according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4). While running I get following warning.

`Fontconfig warning: "/opt/libreoffice4.0/share/fonts/truetype/fc_local.conf", line 13: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected`

Is the warning critical?

What is the problem here?

How can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not critical and is just a matter of the configuration file probably containing values that should have been written differently. You don't need to do anything as it's not going to affect your usage of the program.

It is also probable that this only happens because you are using LibreOffice from the Document Foundation (built for *any* Debian system) and not for Ubuntu specifically (and thus having any Ubuntu-specific patches). Ubuntu builds (such as those in the [LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa)) would have any changes needed to run on Ubuntu already built in.

By the way, I would suggest using this PPA or waiting for newer versions to land in the default repos rather than using the "normal" builds for the above mentioned reason. LibreOffice 4.0 is included in Ubuntu 13.04, so if you are on 12.04 or 12.10, chances are it will come downstream to you as well in the not-so-far future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried upgrading via ppa but 4.0 isn't available yet, so installed deb files.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4.0.1-rc1 packages in ricotz's LibreOffice Backports PPA https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ppa

It says, however:

> THIS IS THE STAGING FOR THE OFFICIAL LIBREOFFICE PPA. The pacakges
>   will be copied there if they turn out well.
>
> INPROGRESS: LibreOffice 4.0 for Precise/12.04 and Quantal/12.10

Apparently they are building the Quantal version (Raring's is already done) of the for the official LibreOffice PPA at the time I am writing this. You should find it soon here: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0