# I have two versions of LibreOffice installed: how to remove the older one?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, uninstall, libreoffice, versions

I think I updated the LibreOffice suite from 4.2 to 4.3 but in fact I have both installed in my Xubuntu 14.04.

The Xfce menu:

[image]

[image]

[image]

A seen above, the older version does not follow the system theme.

Anyway, how to remove the older version and keep the last?

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/265408/327339

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice4.2*
```

What this does is matching of the libreoffice packages with the version 4.2 and removes them.
After removing it is advised to reboot.

Source: http://www.askmetutorials.com/2014/03/install-uninstall-libreoffice-422-on.html

If the "older" version that you want to remove is different than 4.2 or if you want to have a more recent version than the one you have now, you may consider using Synaptic Package Manager to remove all the versions that you installed (searching 'libreoffice') and then

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: I already had removed 4.2 from synaptic when you posted. In this way I only had 4.3.2.2 installed. But then I added the ppa and upgraded libreoffice with the odd result that I found myself with two versions again and the menu looking as in the image posted in the question, 4.3 was there as before, and instead of the 4.2.7.2 version I had v. 4.3.3.2 (a more recent one). I think 4.2 had been installed from ppa already and 4.3.2 had been installed manually. I removed 4.3.2 in synaptic and kept the 4.3.3 version. I think updates will go fine now, although uninstalling older versions may be safer.

Answer (score 4):

I always install libreoffice using the .deb files. When I need to remove an older libreoffice version I use Synaptic. Go to Synaptic, search for `libreoffice`, right click on `libreofficeX.y-core` (X and y is your older version), click on `Mark for Complete Removal`, click on the Apply button and it is done!

Comment: this worked for me for libreoffice 6.x the other answer did not work.