# It is possible to install Openoffice.org on later versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, gnome-classic, openoffice.org

I want to replace Libreoffice with Openoffice.org o Ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME Classic.But i want to install the italian version because I'm italian.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible.

First, you would need to remove LibreOffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then, you need to download Apache OpenOffice from their website: http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html.

Download the Italian "full installation set" for Linux Intel DEB or Linux x86-64 DEB if you are running Ubuntu 64-bit.

Then, follow the installation [instructions](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-deb). In short:

1. Untar the tar.gz file:

   `tar xvf Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_[version]_install-deb_it.tar.gz`
2. Change to the DEBS directory:

   `cd [Apache_OpenOffice_installation_directory]\DEBS`

   The name of the installation directory will likely be the language abbreviation for the install set, e.g. it-IT
3. Install the packages:

   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
4. Install the desktop integration features:

   `cd desktop-integration`
   `sudo dpkg -i [openoffice.org]-debian-menus_[version].deb`
5. Run Apache OpenOffice to check everything is fine, and the you can delete the installation folder.

Now, why install OpenOffice when you can perfectly [install LibreOffice 4.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4), and doing it from the PPA would make your life easier (automatic upgrades instead of repeating the process above over and over).

More importantly, if you look around the internet, you'll find most people recommending LibreOffice over OpenOffice for several reasons.