# Why videos play in Ubuntu-provided LibreOffice, but not in LibreOffice from community-supplied installers?

Tags: video, libreoffice

When I install LibreOffice from Ubuntu repository, import and playing of videos (flv, mp4...) works just fine. If I uninstall that version and install LibreOffice from the LO download page, the same videos neither insert correctly or play. Most recently this happened when I moved to LO4 on my 12.10 laptop. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I just installed from the ppa and get the same result: adding an mp4 using the insert - movie and sound gives me a speaker symbol, no video and very slow interaction, the standard install with 12.04 worked with all video formats.

Answer (score 1):

I've [installed LibreOffice 4.0 from the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4/264047#264047) and have no problem adding a video files (both a large `.mkv` and a large `.avi`) to an Impress presentation.

Not a feature I use, so I wouldn't know if it worked before (with LO installed from the downloaded packages).

However, this issue has been [reported elsewhere](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13844/video-does-not-start-on-impress-lo-40/) (without solution so far).

It may be related to the fact that the LO packages have not been "tailored" specifically for Ubuntu. Try the PPA and let us know.