# Persona issues in LibreOffice 4.0.2.2

Tags: libreoffice

Just wondering are there any issues with the personas in LO 4.0.2.2?? I installed LO 4.0.2.2 as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

It seems to install smoothly, but when I try to add a persona, by pasting a link into the field beside `Own persona` and click `OK` nothing happens.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

PC

Comment: I don't have LO 4 yet, but I believe you have to first install a persona/theme through Firefox as an add-on theme and that LO then pulls the personas from the Firefox list. Do you have any Firefox themes added?

Comment: Well, I'm glad someone found the right answer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It's a great resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice personas stopped working when Mozilla moved them from getpersonas.com to addons.mozilla.org.  LO expects a getpersonas.com url pointing to a persona page, which is impossible because that site no longer exists.

The bug report is here: https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59608

**Update** This has been fixed upstream, so you can get working personas again by installing the updated version from https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0

Comment: I don't seem to be having any problem. I still have mine pointing at a getpersonas.com url and it works fine. I Love LibreOffice 4! Wow!

Comment: getpersonas URLs never stopped working in LO. The problem is that you can't find them any more because mozilla took down the site.

Comment: Yes, personas working again in LO version 4.0.3, good job, nice to see :-) Note that, I had to download version 4.0.3 from the LO website and install manually, as suggested by

Seth at:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4

looks like the version on 

ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0

is still 4.0.2

Comment: @paulc the PPA I linked above has version 4.0.3-0ubuntu1 if you're on raring.

Comment: ahh I see...I am still on 12.04...