# Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected

Tags: 12.10, scripts, libreoffice

```
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/fonts/truetype/fc_local.conf", line 
13: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
```

I run my script in terminal and I have this error. It looks like ubuntu error:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1048552

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a fix has been issued, you can try installing [LibreOffice from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/264047/58950) or downloading and installing the "community-provided" (original) version from [libreoffice.org](http://www.libreoffice.org).

Comment: I used a Linux mint from virtualboxes.org, and had this error on `unoconv`, and the instructions for PPA fixed it. Thanks!