# LibreOffice 4.0 doesn't show modules writer, calc, etc anymore

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I haven't used it for about 2 weeks and today when I wanted to start and .odt file I found out that it doesn't work anymore. I can't find Writer and the rest of them in the search lense but the files with the libreoffice extensions still have libreoffice thumbnails. The only thing I can find is LibreOffice and this appears when I open it (all modules are grayed out)
[image]

I installed 4.0 about a month ago, uninstalling 3.5 that came with Ubuntu 12.04. It worked great

This is not a dublicate as far as I know, the other having problems not seeing the modules in the launcher but they can start them

Comment: Did you install 4 from a PPA or by the manual method? (Like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4/252613#252613))

Comment: Also, that looks like LO3.. Are you sure version 4 didn't get uninstalled by accident? Have you done any upgrade recently or installed a new package?

Comment: Wow I'm seeing the "3" for the first time. I followed the instructions from their web site. Downloaded the tar and uninstalled Libreoffice 3 first. I didn't watch what updates came in the past 2 weeks. Is it possible that some LO3 updates overwrote some of LO4 files?

Comment: Yes, something like that. One of the updates might have removed LO4 because of a dependency issue.. I think you should just reinstall 4 (or if you'd rather 3). Does anything about LO4 show up in the software center?

Comment: The modules appear as not installed. I looked in Synaptic and there it shows that all packages libreoffice4.0* are installed. For the next reinstall I suppose I should remove the ppa?

Comment: I don't know why you would need to remove it..

Comment: @Silviu what is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice` (use paste.ubuntu.com)?