# Libre office is creating a new document every time I click on the launcher icon. How do I stop that and go to the documents I already open?

Tags: launcher, libreoffice

I have the same problem that is already mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/q/187053 but I don't find the answers to that question useful:

I just bought this computer (one week ago) that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 and libre office 3.5.4.2 and I'm not that happy with Libre Office, because I have been crushing several times, closing itself and I need to recover my documents, but the last issue was the same as HU23 mentioned. 
Suddenly the window preview disappear and every time I click on the libre office icon on the side bar it opens a new window. What do I get the bird-eye view preview again and avoid this problem?

Comment: What does the logo in your side bar look like? Is it the LibreOffice Writer Logo (the blue page) or just the LibreOffice logo (white, blank page)?

If it's the Writer Logo, well there's the answer, you're starting LibreOffice Writer which starts with a blank document. If it isn't well, I'm not sure then.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! May I suggest you start by [upgrading your LibreOffice to version 4](http://askubuntu.com/a/264047/58950). Now, to go to to the open file instead of creting a new, blank file, you right-click on the icon and select the name of the application on the menu that appears.

Answer (score 0):

we can solve your crashing issue and might solve your other issue at the same time:

in your web browser, go to libreoffice.org and download version 3.6.6 or 4.0.3  (3.6.6 is further along and is supposed to be more stable, hence the x.x.6 version number as opposed to the x.x.3)

with nautilus (the file manager) go to the folder containing your completely downloaded file.

right click and select EXTRACT

you can read the readme file inside your downloaded file, which basically says:

uninstall the old version first, in you terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
```

enter the folder.

Open Terminal in that folder. (or navigate in your terminal into that folder)

inside the folder go to DEBS folder

```
cd DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

after that still inside DEBS folder

```
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

and you should have the most current stable libreoffice with bug fixes