# install a version of libreoffice or openoffice in Ubuntu 12.04 that will produce Powerpoint compatible presentations?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have seen some bug reports that say LibreOffice 3.7 has fixed an issue with pptx files that makes them compatible with Powerpoint (I am testing with Powerpoint 2010).

I have generated a presentation with LibreOffice 3.5.2 and now I want to save it in a way that will be kept and shown correctly in Powerpoint 2010.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41992

How can I install 3.7 LibreOffice or any something-Office version that will allow me to open the existing presentation and save it in a way that will be good for Powerpoint 2010?

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) is 4.0.3, and can be easily installed in Ubuntu via a terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

That should install everything you would need for the newest version, and it should be fully compatible for .pptx, .ppsx, and .potm (Microsoft 2007/2010 PowerPoint formats) so that you can run the file in Office.

Comment: It seems like once the newer copy is installed, files saved as pptx are not entirely compatible with the new copy: for example, some text in the slides go down below the bottom limit, and the auto-resizing of the text when adding more bullet points also doesn't work.

Comment: You can try re-saving as an alternate format (.ppsx, .potm, etc.) but this appears to be more of a question suited for LibreOffice support forums as opposed to AskUbuntu at this point.  Try http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/ to figure out how to properly align the documents between both Office suites.

Comment: Thanks, they have an ask.libreoffice.org website, I'll try my luck there after having successfully installed a newer version.