# LibreOffice 4 is not working

Tags: 12.04

Following error is appearing during installation....
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:3.5.7) but it is not installed
"

Pls help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What steps did you follow in your attempt to install LibreOffice 4.x? Have a look at [How do I install LibreOffice 4?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252612/88802) for the "recommended" way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

where do you get your libreoffice from? did you download a .deb or just from the software center? it looks like it expects a package libreoffice-common should be installed because it depends upon it, but for some reason it isn't. you can install the package by opening a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common` enter your password and see wether that works. afterward try to install Libreoffice again.