# In which repository is Libreoffice to be found?

Tags: libreoffice

I can't seem to find libreoffice in the repositories. I would please like to know where to find a copy of this office suite.

Comment: @EliahKagan I know its not asking about version 4 in specific. Libreoffice 4.1, is not available until Saucy, 4.0 is available now.  Glad to have you back :)

Comment: LibreOffice is in the repos with the package name `libreoffice`.

Comment: This is not about LibreOffice 4; the answers [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4) are irrelevant to this question, which should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally find LibreOffice on the Ubuntu Software Center (an application that is normally installed on your computer).
Just type LibreOffice on the text field on the top left of this application and it should show you LibreOffice.

Actually it should be preinstalled with Ubuntu so you should find it in your application (<kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows key) + <kbd>A</kbd> to access your applications).

Comment: Only some LibreOffice components (the most commonly used ones) are installed by default; to get the full suite with all available features, the `libreoffice` package can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since LibreOffice is an office suite, it provides multiple applications, and also supports the addition of features provided by even more packages.

Most components of LibreOffice are in the Main repository. However, a few of them are in the Universe repository (which is still official, but is maintained by the community, rather than by Canonical).

The package called `libreoffice` provides a full installation (by depending on all the packages that, taken together, comprise a full installation). Since the most fully featured installation of LibreOffice contains some components provided by Universe, the `libreoffice` package must be in Universe too, even though *most* of what gets installed is in Main.

If you don't want to enable the Universe repository, you can just install the individual LibreOffice applications you need. These are provided by packages named `libreoffice-` followed by the lower-case name of the package:

- `libreoffice-writer` (Writer, the word processor)
- `libreoffice-calc` (Calc, the spreadsheet)
- `libreoffice-impress` (Impress, the presentation creation app comparable to MS PowerPoint)
- `libreoffice-base` (Base, the database)
- `libreoffice-draw` (Draw, the vector graphics editor)
- `libreoffice-math` (Math, the equation editor)

Or, you can [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and just install the package called `libreoffice`.

Note that if you just install the individual components but keep Universe disabled, you won't get packages like [`fonts-sil-gentium-basic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/fonts-sil-gentium-basic). (Actually, in Ubuntu 13.04, that appears to *possibly* be the only package you won't get.) A [list of all the packages that `libreoffice` causes to be installed is here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libreoffice); if you click on a package you can see if it's in Universe or Main.

Comment: Thank you all for the heads up. Problem now solved. It was really very simple - I am just SO stupid some days! :-D