# error installing libreoffice 4-0

Tags: installation, libreoffice

I had installed LibreOffice 4.0.4, then I added PPA LibreOffice 4-1, and installed new version (LO 4-1). However, there is menu delay problem, so I decided to remove 4-1 and install 4-0 again...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

LO 4-1 was removed, but now I cannot install 4-0.

This is error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libreoffice :
Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.0.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-filter-mobiledev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:4.0.2~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3.3-uno but it is not installable or
                         python3-uno (>= 4.0~) but it is not going to be installed or
                         python-uno but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                            libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install "ure" from Synaptic Package Manager but in options I had to select to "force previous version", ie. 4.0.2.... after that, I was able to install Libre Office...

Answer (score 0):

To install LibreOffice 4 you will need to completely remove all previous versions. Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then install by:-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or get the more details you can see this Q.: [How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4)