# cannot install packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice

I have trouble install packages with apt-get. I get the following error:

```
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For every package I'm trying to install.

I've tried following the discussions in:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1889732
[error installing libreoffice 4-0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329291/error-installing-libreoffice-4-0)

but had no success.

can anyone help?

---

ok thanks. I solved by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common python3-uno libreoffice-*
```

for some reason removing each package separately has failed but in the same command - it worked

Answer (score 2):

The OP solved the problem himself [in the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/525037/3):

> I solved by running:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common python3-uno libreoffice-*
> ```
>
> for some reason removing each package separately has failed but in the same command - it worked