# How do I install LibreOffice on 10.04 Server?

Tags: installation, server, libreoffice

I follow @Seth's answer to install LibreOffice4 on the server.

[How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4)

I run `dpkg -i *.deb` without any error (as root). Then I didn't see any `desktop-integration` folder. Then nothing. There is no `libreoffice` command.

Basically, I try to use `libreoffice` to run in server mode, and convert `odt` file to `pdf` file (with python subprocess module). I can do that locally, but I cannot figure out how to install libreoffice on the server, where there is no GUI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running any Desktop Environment,or just Terminal?

Comment: @Mitch May I suggest a Desktop Environment, as LibreOffice is an application suite with X support ?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith You may do so for the OP.

Comment: The link given in the question points out the use of PPAs and apt-get packages manager. Try using them instead of dpkg ?

Comment: @Mitch just terminal

Answer (score 2):

My fault. With help of colleague, it turns out the command is `libreoffice4.1` instead of `libreoffice`. So I had successfully installed libreoffice.

But to share about how to call libreoffice on Ubuntu server version, there are some additional library to be installed.

```
# for X11 support
apt-get install xorg
apt-get install openbox

# for libdbus
aptitude install libc6
aptitude install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

And to convert to pdf, must specify `writer_pdf_Export` in my case.

```
libreoffice4.1 --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export result.odt --outdir /path/to/outdir
```