# Newest Libre Office Isn't Installing Through PPA

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, ppa, libreoffice

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've followed the directions closely here:

[How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4#)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-1  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to add the PPA repository and then run update / upgrade.

But when I actually run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating upgrade... Done  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I've downloaded the file manually (LibreOffice_4.2.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz) and executed it but I don't know how to fill out the command line arguments:

```
~/Downloads/LibreOffice_4.2.1.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm$ ./install  
Usage: ./install [-a,--add] [-l,--link] [-U,--update] [-h,--help] <rpm-source-dir> <office-installation-dir>
Example: ./install . ~/libreoffice
```

I should probably be doing `./install -u /path/to/install/here`

But how do I know where Libre Office is installed to right now? I'd like to upgrade my current version not install two side by side so I want to get these command line paramters right.

Comment: The directions you follower were...?

Comment: fixed my post. I added the PPA and got nothing to upgrade afterwards.

Comment: why don't you just download the .deb file available in the website?

Comment: the file from the website came with 51 .deb files when unpackaged and running sudo dpkg -i *.deb returned:  cannot access archive: No such file or directory