# Cannot open xlsx files with LibreOffice Calc, application is grayed out

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to open some xlsx files created probably from MS Office Excell app, and the Calc just grays out after trying to load the file, and results to a non-responsive state.
The only thing I can do is force a quit.

I've tried updating LibreOffice and now I have this version: `3.5.7.2`.
Still no luck.

Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should update LibreOffice to a more recent version, as you are running a very old one (almost two years). You should try with LibreOffice 4.1.5.

This is how you can do that, as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```