# Install libreoffice 4 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice

How do I install an older version of LibreOffice than LibreOffice 5.0?

none of the hints here helped:

[How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4)

Comment: I've just started using LibreOffice 5 and wonder what advantages version 4 has over it? Could version 5 disadvantage be fixed some how? My details: Version: 5.1.4.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1
CPU Threads: 8; OS Version: Linux 4.6; UI Render: default;

Comment: I have a db that only works with 4

Comment: Have you looked at http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/ ?

Comment: @DKBose This should be an answer. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem will do if no one beats me to it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/ for older versions.

There are .`deb` files there. However, it's possible that there maybe some conflicts over dependencies. So you'd be on your own.