# Can I remote control my Ubuntu laptop from an Android phone without using the Internet?

Tags: networking, android, remote-desktop

Can I remote control my Ubuntu laptop from an Android phone without using the Internet?

I would like to use VNC or a similar method to remote control my Ubuntu 15.10 graphically or over command-line.

There are tools such as Teamviewer but I don't want to use them because they are slow and require an Internet connection, which I don't always have.

If I really need to, I have a router in the bag which I could use, but I would prefer solutions which do not involve a router.

Any ideas or solutions?

Vesa

Comment: Teamviewer can work over the LAN

Comment: What kind of data connection do you wish to use?

Comment: did the solution work for you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Android phone control Ubuntu like a remote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122760/can-an-android-phone-control-ubuntu-like-a-remote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it and its free.

1) **Install any VNC server** from the list like 
TightVNC, UltraVNC, TigerVNC, or RealVNC, although encryption is not supported with the latter.

2) Create a **hotspot** and connect your laptop and your Android phone in the same network.

3) Install **[bVNC Secure VNC Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freebVNC)** on your Android phone.

The bVNC app is a VNC viewer.It can also emulate a touchpad or let you use Android as a mouse with support for touchscreen gestures. You can save sessions, zoom and scale the Linux desktop on the Android screen, and share the text in the clipboard between Android and PC.

And EnjoY.. !!!!!!!

Comment: Remember, I don't want to use the Internet. Are you saying that if I create a mobile hotspot on a mobile device and connect both my laptop and a phone to the same hotspot I will be able to use VNC to communicate between them?

Comment: Its not necessary to give internet.. Use your router or mobile to create hotspot without internet and it shud work fi9